# Calculating probabilities in Python

Tags: python, probability

I'm trying to write a script that computes the probability of choosing random elements from a given list. Here is what I have so far:

```
import random

a = [11, 12, 13, 14]
b = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
c = [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]

total = a+b+c


print ("Choosing 3 random items from any list")
sampled_list = random.sample(total, 3)
print(sampled_list)
```

With this script I can choose three random elements without replacement. Now I want to compute the probability that the random list generated will include, for example, two elements from list b, or an element from each list. How should I go about this? Is my choice of numbers in a list not the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Could you give an example of a calculation you want? For example "two elements from list b" are you wanting the calculation (5/15)*(4/14)? The "one element from each list" will involve a sum over the combinations of choices.

Comment: Use monte carlo sampling. Do this sampling say N (a large number) times. Count how many times out of these N times your condition is satisfied. Divide to get the approximate probability. Increase N to get a better approximation.

Comment: How would I set up a Monte Carlo sampling? Forgive me, I'm pretty weak in Python programming.

Comment: Bobby Ocean, yes, the calculation (5.15)*(4.14) is kind of what I'm looking for. More specifically, I want to be able to tell the program to calculate a probability for choosing a certain number of elements from any combination of lists. Running the simulation 1000 times or so should get me a rather accurate answer. I know a for loop could be used in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would do Monte Carlo sampling for your first task (containing exactly two elements from B).

The broad idea is to check whether a particular sample satisfies whatever condition you have and increment a variable (`counter`) here. The approximate probability is then `counter / N`.

```
import random

a = [11, 12, 13, 14]
b = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
c = [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]

total = a+b+c

N = 1000
counter = 0

for _ in range(N):
    sampled_list = random.sample(total, 3)
    els_in_b = 0
    for el in sampled_list:
        if el in b:
            els_in_b += 1
    if els_in_b == 2:
        counter += 1

print(counter / N)
```

Comment: Please note that you can speed this up by replacing the `if el in b` with a set lookup.

Comment: May I ask what a set lookup is?

Comment: The script looks good, but the probability it gives me does not agree with the paper result. I get about 0.2967, whereas the script gives me probabilities of 0.14...

Comment: @billyyank Hi I changed the code a bit sometime ago, are you running the correct version? I get 0.2242 for N = 10^4. However, that still does not explain the difference in output. Could I see the paper?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but at least it gives a simple solution that can be easily read and expanded.

```
import random

a = [11, 12, 13, 14]
b = [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
c = [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]

total = a+b+c

# Decide how many samples you want.
samples = 100

# Define an empty vector.
combs = []

# Get the possible outcomes of number of elements per list.
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        for k in range(0,4):
            if(i + j + k == 3):
                combs = combs + [[i,j,k]]
            
# Count of how many elements per group
accum = [0 for x in combs]

# Perform the experiment a number of times given the sample.
for i in range(samples):

    # Auxiliary variables.
    totalEnt = [0,0,0]
    sampled_list = random.sample(total, 3)

    # Store the number of elements that belong to each list.
    totalEnt[0] = [x in a for x in sampled_list].count(True)
    totalEnt[1] = [x in b for x in sampled_list].count(True)
    totalEnt[2] = [x in c for x in sampled_list].count(True)

    # According to the result add to the proper counter. 
    idx = combs.index(totalEnt)
    accum[idx] += 1

# Print the probabilities.
print("[elements in a, elements in b, elements in c]: Probability")
for i, elem in enumerate(accum):
    print(str(combs[i]) + ": " + str(elem/samples))
```

Comment: Of course, you can modify it to include more lists. Just need a good way to add combinatorics to building the vector of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is just probability theory.
You only have to calculate the number of valid possibilities and divide it by the total number of possibilities.

So, we need an equation for calculating the number of possible combinations, or `nCr`:

```py
from math import factorial

def nCr(n, r):
    return(factorial(n)//(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r)))
```

Now that we have that, we can calculate easily what the probability is of choosing the numbers in a specific way.
Let's say we have a list of 3 values, each saying how many values were taken from a particular list.
So, for example, if we want to have 2 from list 1 and 1 from list 2, we can calculate the probability that this happens when we randomly choose 3 out of a set of all lists, with:

```py
from functools import reduce
import operator

# Define product function
def prod(iterable):
    return(reduce(operator.mul, iterable, 1))


# Define lists
numbers = [
    [11, 12, 13, 14],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]
    ]

# Define how many are taken from each
n_taken = [2, 1, 0]


# Calculate number of values in each list
n_values = list(map(len, numbers))

# Calculate total number of values
n_total = sum(n_values)

# Calculate number of ways numbers can be taken this way
N1 = prod(map(nCr, n_values, n_taken))

# Calculate total number of possibilities
N2 = nCr(n_total, sum(n_taken))

# Divide the two
print(N1/N2)
```

Output: `0.06593406593406594` or about 6.6%.

You can modify the `numbers` and `n_taken` lists to add more lists or more numbers to the lists.

Comment: If you want to know the probability of getting 2 from the second list for drawing 3 for example, you add the probabilities of `n_taken = [1, 2, 0]` and `n_taken = [0, 2, 1]` together, which gives `0.13186813186813187 + 0.08791208791208792 = 0.21978021978021978`.